# Smaller underline effect

Tags: html, css

I came across interesting underline effect that looks like this:

[image: CSS smaller underline]

It's simple, but I can't think of a way to achieve it without using additional html elements in markup, that will be not semantic. I am wondering if it is possible to achieve it using css and without having any additional elements. Effect is essentially an underline / bottom border that is smaller than element and centered under it.

Here is my markup for navigation, where this effect will be used on current page links.

```
            <nav id="navigation" class="right">
                <ul>
                    <li> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#">About</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#">Work</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#">Blog</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one - http://jsbin.com/lumasive/1/

```
#navigation li a { position:relative; }
#navigation li a:after {
      content: '';
      position:absolute;
      bottom:0;
      left: 30%;
      right: 30%;
      height: 2px;
      background:red;
      display:block;
}
```

Comment: worked, thanks! will accept the answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

same as others , the use of a pseudo , but in the flow: **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cbfxE)**

```
li ,a { 
  display:inline-block;
  color:#EE7972;
  font-size:40px;
  font-variant:small-caps;
  text-decoration:none;
}
a {
  margin:1em;
}
a:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  height:0.2em;
  width:35%;
  margin:auto;
  border-bottom:solid ;
}

   a:hover {
      color:turquoise;/* change color of text and mini-border*/
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Without additional HTML:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsBBX/1/)

You can use the "after" css property:

```
a:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content:"__";
  width: 100%; top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `:after` pseudo-element to append extra markup your `a` elements:

Like all the other answers, but perhaps a little less CSS required.

```
a:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-bottom: solid 1px steelblue;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qebHo

Answer (score 1):

use "after" property to achieve this. : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZwP4k/)

CSS:

```
.right ul li a{
    position:relative;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.right ul li a:after{
    content: '';
      position:absolute;
      bottom:0;
      left: 30%;
      right: 30%;
      background:black;
    height:1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can as well use linear backgrounds: **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IcHKC)** or  **[DEMO 2](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BeKAn)**

CSS demo 1

```
a {
  margin:1em;
  padding-bottom:0.2em;
  background:linear-gradient(
    to left,
  transparent 33%, 
    #EE7972 33%, 
    #EE7972 66%, 
    transparent 66%
  )
    bottom no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 3px;
}
```

CSS demo 2

```
a {
  margin:1em;
  padding-bottom:0.2em;
  background:linear-gradient(
    to left, 
    #EE7972 , 
    #EE7972 
  )
    bottom no-repeat;
  background-size: 1em 3px;
}
```

Possible animation with this border: **[border animated](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/IGliC)**

Comment: this kind of fake borders can be animated too, reset background-size, color, position via animation or transition to get somme cool effects http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pKwby