# Underlining some pixels shorter than the headline

Tags: css

I need to underline a heading in a way that the underline is shorter (and centered) than the heading. Like:

```
BIGTITLE
  ---
```

Can this be done easily in CSS ?

Comment: this one too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263283/achieve-following-underline-effect-with-css-and-as-few-html-elements-as-possible